# Passing data using jQuery Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the html page below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <title>HTML</title>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#b1").click(function(event) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type : "POST",
                        url : "index.php",
                        data : "valx=2",
                        contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        dataType : "text",
                        complete : function() {
                            alert('post completed');
                        },
                        error : function() {
                            alert('error condition');
                        },
                        success : function(data) {
                            $('.result').html(data);
                            alert('data is returned');
                        },

                        statusCode : {
                            200 : function() {
                                alert("page was found");
                            }
                        }

                    });
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <button id="b1">
                Click Me!
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="result"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

And then I have the following php page:

```
<?php
     $my_string =  $_REQUEST["valx"]; 
     $my_string = $my_string +9;
     echo $my_string;
?>
```

Everything works perfectly as is, but I was trying to figure out how to change the post data to the form:

```
 data: '{ valx:"2"}'
```

And this is where it breaks. I tried many forms of data: '{ valx:"2"}' and still no luck. It seems as if the php script is not getting the data correctly. Also note that using this format it seems that `contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",` needs to be changed as well.

So the question is how do you pass data of the form `data: '{ valx:"2"}'` and get back a response of 11?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: without quotes data : {valx:2}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data parameter accepts a `var=value&var1=value1` form, *or* a JavaScript object with keys/values. You've given it this, which is a string...

```
data: '{ valx:"2"}`
```

... when you should have given it this, which is a real JS object:

```
data: { valx:"2"}
```

Comment: Ok that works- thanks Meager! So data: { valx:"2"} being the only change works fine. However I thought this should be changed as well: contentType: 'application/json',  But if I change the content type it breaks again. Isn't the content type supposed to contentType: 'application/json' ?

Answer (score 0):

Use an object not a string. jQuery will parse the object into form encoded format. Also remove your `contentType` option completely since this is not the type of data being sent, rather it is for data received and you will be receiving text/html

```
 data : { valx:"2"},
```